# Why is numba throwing an error regarding numpy methods when (nopython=True)?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to use numba to improve the speed of some code that I've written that is rather slow. The majority of the time spent is in a single function. First I tried using just

```
@jit
```

before my function definition, which improved timing a bit. Then, I tried using

```
@jit(nopython=True)
```

instead. From what I've read in the documentation, the numpy methods that I am using within the function should be supported (e.g. transpose). However, I am getting an error

```
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'transpose'
```

Comment: A complete list of numpy supported features can be found at the following link. Also, post code and which version you are using otherwise it's hard to diagnose what's going wrong: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to check which version I am using. 'numba --verison' doesn't seem to work. I think it's 0.27.0, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `numba.__version__`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use `transpose`, you need to call it (as the docs [describe](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#other-methods)) in the form of a method of a numpy array. So the following works:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def func(x):
    y = x.transpose()  # or x.T
    return y

x = np.random.normal(size=(4,4))
x_t = func(x)
```

But calling `y = np.transpose(x)` in the function does not. I assume you're doing the latter. Note, I'm using Numba 0.25.0 for reference.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was using numpy.transpose(x).